# Server can't find: SERVFAIL or REFUSE DNS

Tags: linux, dns, debian, bind

I'm trying to setup a DNS Server using Debian but I keep getting errors when I do nslookup like SERVFAIL or REFUSED.
I want to use 3 virtual machines (VM1, VM2 and VM3) and call them that by those names in the DNS Server, I'm using VMWare Workstation 11.

Here is my configuration:

*named.conf.options*

```
options {
directory "/var/cache/bind";
additional-from-auth no;
additional-from-cache no;

// If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
// to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
// ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

// If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
// nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
// Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
// the all-0's placeholder.

 forwarders {
    192.168.207.2;
    192.168.207.133;
};

//========================================================================
// If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
// you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
//========================================================================
dnssec-validation yes;
allow-recursion{127.0.0.1;};
auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

*named.conf.local*

```
    zone "linux.local"{
    type master;
    file "etc/bind/db.linux.local";
};

zone "207.168.192-in-addr.arpa"{
    type master;
    file "etc/bind/db.207.168.192";
};
```

*db.linux.local*

```
;
; SOA 
; 
$TTL 1h 
@   IN SOA vm1.linux.local. root.linux.local. ( 
        1 ; Serial number (YYYYMMDDnn) 
        1h ; Slave refresh 
        15m ; Slave retry 
        2w ; Slave expire 
        1h ; Cache TTL
     ) 
; 
; NS RECORDS 
; 
@   IN   NS  vm1.linux.local.  
; 
; A RECORDS 
;

linux.local.    IN A 192.168.207.133 
@       IN A 192.168.207.133 
vm1         IN A 192.168.207.133 
vm3         IN A 192.168.207.135
vm2     IN A 192.168.207.130 
vmware      iN A 192.168.207.2
```

*db.207.168.192*

```
$TTL 1h 
@ IN SOA vm1.linux.local. root.linux.local. (
    1;
    1h;
    15m;
    2w;
    1h;
) 

    IN  NS  vm1.linux.local. 
133 IN  PTR     linux.local. 
133     IN  PTR     vm1.linux.local. 
135     IN  PTR     vm2.linux.local.
130 IN  PTR     vm3.linux.local. 
2   IN  PTR     vmware.linux.local.
```

Here is the nslookup for VM1 and linux.local:

```
root@debian:/etc/bind# nslookup vm1
Server:     192.168.207.133
Address:    192.168.207.133#53

** server can't find vm1: REFUSED

root@debian:/etc/bind# nslookup linux.local
Server:     192.168.207.133
Address:    192.168.207.133#53

** server can't find linux.local.linux.local: SERVFAIL
```

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but did you start the service? Is bind or named running and listening: `netstat -taupn | grep :53`

Comment: I started the service but the IP of the server was 192.168.207.132, I've copied it wrong and that was the problem. I've solved it, but thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

maybe the access is limited. try edit the file `named.conf`, change or add options `allow-query { any;};`

Answer (score 1):

run

```
rndc-confgen >> /etc/named.conf
```

This should fix the issue.

Comment: The IP of the server was 192.168.207.132 instead of 192.168.207.133. For some dumb reason I copied it wrong but thanks for the help anyway.